# Reading csv into Rstudio from google cloud storage

Tags: r, google-cloud-storage, read.csv

I want to read csv file from google cloud storage with a function similar to

> read.csv.

I used library **googleCloudStorageR** and I can't find a function for that. I don't want to download it, I just want to read it in environment like a data frame.

Comment: See: https://code.markedmondson.me/googleCloudStorageR/reference/gcs_get_object.html "... By default if you want to get the object straight into an R session the parseFunction is gcs_parse_download which wraps httr's content. ..." 
Also related: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/httr/versions/1.4.1/topics/content

Answer (score 1):

If you download a .csv file, googleCloudStorageR will by default put it into a data.frame for you via `write.csv` - you can turn off the behaviour by specifying `saveToDisk`

```r
# will make a data.frame
gcs_get_object("mtcars.csv")

# save to disk as a CSV
gcs_get_object("mtcars.csv", saveToDisk = "mtcars.csv")
```

You can specify your own parse function by supplying it via `parseFunction`

```r
## default gives a warning about missing column name.
## custom parse function to suppress warning
f <- function(object){
  suppressWarnings(httr::content(object, encoding = "UTF-8"))
}

## get mtcars csv with custom parse function.
gcs_get_object("mtcars.csv", parseFunction = f)
```

Answer (score 0):

I’ve tried running a sample csv file with the as.data.frame() function.

In order to run this code snippet make sure you install (install.packages("data.table")) and included the library library(“data.table”)
Also be sure that you include the fread() within the as.data.frame() function in order to read the file from it’s location.

Here is the code snippet I ran and managed to display the data frame for my data set:

```
library(“data.table”)

MyData <- as.data.frame(fread(file="$FILE_PATH",header=TRUE, sep = ','))

print(MyData)
```

Reading Data with TensorFlow:

There is one other way you can read a csv from your cloud storage with the TensorFlow API. I would assume you are accessing this data from a bucket? Firstly, you would need to install the “readr” and “cloudml” packages for these functionalities to work. Then you would need to use gs_data_dir(“gs://your-bucket-name”) along with specifying the file path file.path(data_dir, “something.csv”). You would then want to read data from the file path with **read_csv**(file.path(data_dir, “something.csv”)). If you want it formatted as a data frame it should look something like this.

```
library(“data.table”)
library(cloudml)
library(readr)

data_dir <- gs_data_dir(“gs://your-bucket-name”)

MyData <- as.data.frame(read_csv(file.path(data_dir, “something.csv”)))

print(MyData)
```

Make sure you have properly authenticated access to your storage

More information in this [link](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/cloudml/vignettes/storage.html)